# Why I cannot see the plot of the line?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hello I am programming using Python and I have this problem :

Here is my code :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
y = ['Physics','Chemistry','Economics','Philosophy','Computer 
Science','Sociology','Biology','History','Overall']
x = [0.0,33.333333333333336,50.0,50.0,50.0,54.54545454545455,58.333333333333336,100.0,51.851851851851855]
plt.barh(y,x)
plt.plot(x,x) # not possible to see this plot
plt.title('Percent Completion Rate of Each Course')
plt.show()
```

This plot : `plt.plot(x,x)` is not visible on my figure. Here is the result of `plt.show()` :

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BfAi.png)

Coud you help me please ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: [This is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5QpK.png) the output when I run your code, where the line is visible. (Though it doesn't make much sense, but I suppose that's on a different level.) Maybe you want to tell how you run your code, which versions you are using etc.. such that one can reproduce this.

Comment: Do you expect the second plot to overlap the first, or one next to each other?

Comment: Your line shows up on my plot when I run your code as well. Please provide some more details and context.

Comment: No I cannot see the lines using Python3

Comment: works for me python 3.6.5...try plt.clf() and plt.close() and try again

Comment: I try but it does not work :/